# text scroll inside edittext of a linear layout which in scrollview in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollbar

I have an UI issue like, some `EditText` s are there in `LinearLayout` ,and this linear layout is placed in scroll view . now what i want to do is  edit text has large amount of data for seeing this data i have set `android:scrollbars ="vertical"`  by  this i'm able to see the scroll bar inside the edit text but the data is not scrolling. out side `scrollbar` is moving.how to fix this issue.

can anybody help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you....

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
                        findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG,"CHILD TOUCH");
                         //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

In your case 'parentScrollView' is your scrollView while childScrollView is your Linearlayout/EditText

Answer (score 1):

Use `yourEditTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`